# Change directory using ls | tail -1

Tags: cd-command

I want to go in the directory on the basis of highest directory number.

Path: `/home/cg/root/2018/01`.     Inside this path I have multiple directories as below

```
15
16
17
So on..
```

In this case highest directory is `17` so I want to move in `17` directory... If a directory named `18` exists then want to go in `18`.

Is there any way which can be done using the `cd` command?

Like :

```
cd /home/cg/root/2018/01/$(ls |tail -1)
```

Comment: gratuitous zsh: `cd $(zsh -c 'echo *(/on[-1])')`

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` `sort` and `head` to do this

`cd $(find /home/cg/root/2018/01/* -type d | sort -r | head -1)` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks for quick turn around, however I got below exception.          Find: paths must precede expression......

Comment: The correct syntax is: cd $(find /home/cg/root/2018/01 -type d | sort -r | head -1)

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```
cd $(ls /home/cg/root/2018/01 | sort -n -r | awk 'NR==1 {print $1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a (temporary) bash array inside a function:

```
cdhighest() {
  local dirs=(/home/cg/root/2018/01/*)
  cd -- "${dirs[-1]}"
}
```

Then just run `cdhighest` and it will take you to the directory under /home/cg/root/2018/01 that sorts last.

Reference:

- [Does the Bash star * wildcard always produce an (ascending) sorted list?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/368507/117549)

Answer (score 0):

What you have pretty much looks like it should work, except that `ls` should of course be told to list the contents of the correct directory. But it wouldn't list the full paths and there's a bunch of other details. Plus the things listed in [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Since the shell can list filenames, and it actually sorts them, we could use just `printf` with a glob:

```
$ cd "$(printf "%s\n" /home/cg/root/2018/01/*/ |tail -1)"
```

Of course, that requires the directory names don't contain newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in simple way.

```
cd /home/cg/root/2018/01; cd `ls -r | head -n 1`
```