# How to force bash star * wildcard expanding in ascending order for numerical values?

Tags: bash, for, bash-expansion

Please assume that we are now within a directory containing 13 files that were named as follows:

```
p1 p2 p3 ... p11 p12 p13
```

Through **bash**, when we execute the following command:

```
for i in p*; do echo $i; done
```

The star * wildcard seems to be expanded **without an ascending order**:

```
p1
p10
p11
...
p7
p8
p9
```

Yet for example, the following piece of commands expand the numerical values in an ascending order:

```
for i in p{1..13}; do echo $i; done
```

Is there any bash settings to alter this default star * wildcard behaviour?

If not, could you please tell us what is the motivation behind this preference for such an expansion?

PS: For a similar question, please refer to: [Does the Bash star * wildcard always produce an (ascending) sorted list?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368318/does-the-bash-star-wildcard-always-produce-an-ascending-sorted-list). Yet herein I wonder if we can change the default behaviour of bash, and if so, how?

Comment: Let us know why you think lexicographical sorting of  these files is counter-intuitive. Also consider that filenames may be on any form, e.g. `file-1-1001`, `file-1-1002` ... `file-1-1999` or from `file-A-1001` through to `file-Z-1001` followed by `file-A-1002` etc. What would be the "intuitive" numerical sorting for these?

Comment: `bash` _has no setting_ to alter the order of glob expansion. Those who can't/don't want to use `zsh` have two options: either rename the files (zero-padding the numbers) or resort to contortions like `for f in p? p?? p???; do...`

Comment: @Kusalananda Your observation is definitely correct. The word 'intuitive' is not quantifiable, yet a subjective object (but, I tried to cover it with 'IMHO' in my defence). Therefore, I edited my question, and removed those words. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is essentially no. More info is given in the duplicate.